# Compile time flamegraph performance comparison issue

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, template-meta-programming

I am currently re-writing a compile-time regular expression library that I had written some time ago, but the build time of the new version is drastically slower than the old version (~7.5s for the new version vs ~2.5s for the old version on my benchmark).

So, to analyse the build process I created compilation flamegraphs using clang's `-ftime-trace`:

```bash
clang++ -I. -std=c++20 -ftime-trace -c main.cpp # Old library version
clang++ -I. -std=c++20 -ftime-trace -c main2.cpp # New library version
```

As expected, the flag slows down the compilation, but the problem is that it reverses the behaviour: the new version builds in ~12s while the old one now builds in ~16s.

While I can still technically use the new build's flamegraph to optimise it, I am wondering how much the flamegraph generation impacts the performance of the build process and the represented times. As the two libraries are drastically different, the results above suggest that some code which is fast to build without the flag becomes really slow when the flamegraph is generated.

Would someone have some insight on how to deal with this?

Comment: Very obvious that the flame graph causes a significant slowdown by your own account. You should look into the graph for insights not total time.

Comment: That is indeed what I am doing, but I am still wondering if someone has insights into why some code causes a less than 2x slowdown but the other causes more than a 6x slowdown, which would help me better investigate the performance issues. My rewrite has plenty of change: I use variadic templates to store type lists instead of templated linked lists, I use wrapper types instead of NTTP packs, I use overload resolution to map types... so the factor difference could come from a lot of places, and knowing what the flamegraph struggles with could really help me have better insights.

Comment: That's not the question you asked. You asked about the time difference between a regular run and a `-ftime-trace` run. That time difference is irrelevant to finding out why your library change got slower.

Comment: I see, maybe I just cannot use the flamegraph for this use case and should instead focus on more precise benchmarks.

Comment: 99/100 times I see compile time projects its just academic rhetoric. Even CTRE is much slower even to re2 which is C

Comment: @Alex: "*maybe I just cannot use the flamegraph for this use case*" Um... why not? Why can't you look at the graph and see what it says? Why do you think the graph is illegitimate or otherwise not appropriate to your original use case?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Yeah it's not really a serious projet with the first version I just wanted to practice templates and the second version is cleaning things up, creating compile-time data structures... and trying to leverage C++17/20(/23 maybe)'s new compile-time features (folds, NTTP with objects, concepts...). Also, AFAIK CTRE nicely parses the regex with a (awesome) compile-time parser then uses a recursive implementation for the evaluation whereas my implementation doesn't parse the regex (I leverage C++'s own parser) but then transforms it to a finite automaton for O(len(s)) complexity

Comment: @NicolBolas If both slowdown rates were the same (like both +2s or both x2 or even both x6), then I would assume this is just the profiler overhead. But because there is such a dissimularity, I believe that there is something in my first implementation that causes the profiler to be so much slower. But as the program is huge (in terms of templates), what if that thing also happens within one implementation? What if my first algorithm in the second implementation is actually fast, but causes the profiler to go slower and so I believe wrongly that I should optimize that part.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't mean that I cannot use the flamegraph at all, just that I should first have benchmarks for each specific algorithm and not for the whole chain. By having benchmarks for each algorithm, I can compare them without the profiler first, and then use the profiler only on the algorithm to have insights on how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

> Would someone have some insight on how to deal with this?

There's nothing to deal with. The point of using a profiler of any kind is to find where the slowdown is happening. The raw performance of instrumented code is *irrelevant* to finding the bottlenecks, because the goal is to find the bottlenecks in the *uninstrumented* version. How fast the profiler runs isn't the point; what the profiler says about how fast the *optimized* version runs is what matters.

That is, you should not discount the information the instrumented run gave you just because the overall runtime of the instrumented version changed disproportionately. What you're looking for is how much time is being spent on which processes in the optimized code. And the graphs should tell you that.